# split unordered lists with same class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to split a few ul's which have the same class "dropdown_4columns". I want to wrap every 15th li item in a div called "column". The script I use does that actually but grabs li items from the next ul dropdown_4columns. So how can I just split the li items for just the current list. I can't use css3 columns and can't change classes or id's. It's all generated automatically! I tried to use closest, find and $this but without any luck :(

```
<ul class="nav clearfix">
  <li class="item">
     <ul class="dropdown_4columns">
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
     <ul class="dropdown_4columns">
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
     <ul class="dropdown_4columns">
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$().ready(function(){  

  var divs = $("ul.dropdown_4columns > li");
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=15) {
    divs.slice(i, i+15).wrapAll("<div class='column'></div>");
  }
});
```

Comment: ok, first of all, `$().ready(function(){` should be `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @pythonian29033: Ok you're right but that's not the question ;)

Comment: @pythonian29033 It could also be `$(function(){ ... });` ;)

Comment: Also... please don't wrap your LI items in a div... it's not proper HTML.

Comment: I know Jaap, and that wasn't an answer, just something I noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the ULs and *then* loop through the LIs:

```
$(".dropdown_4columns").each(function)) {
    var divs = $(this).children("li");
    //split code here
});
```

(untested, just for concept)

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
var divs = $("ul.dropdown_4columns").first().find("li");
```

Ye, if you want all, then like so:

```
$("ul.dropdown_4columns").each(function(){
   $(this).find("li")...
});
```

Comment: What's this supposed to do?

Comment: @reyaner: Ahh ok, that did the trick! So basically select the first available?! I'll accept this as the correct answer... thx!

Comment: This only processes the first UL, though.

Comment: @reyaner: Oow Richard is correct this only processes the first ul, any help with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('.dropdown_4columns').each(function () {

    // Check the number of lis in each div with class 'dropdown_4columns'
    // This is for debug purpose only, you can remove it if you want..
    console.log('Length: ' + $(this).children('li').length);

    // Get all the lis in each div with class 'dropdown_4columns'
    var divs = $(this).children('li');

    // Use your code now
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 15) {
        divs.slice(i, i + 15).wrapAll("<div class='column'></div>");
    }
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KjD8a/)

Answer (score 1):

okay here's the code you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul.dropdown_4columns").each(function(){
      var fifteenthLi = $(this).children("li").eq(14);
      fifteenthLi.replaceWith("<div class='column'>" + fifteenthLi[0].outerHTML + "</div>")
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Neat and simple... works like a charm.

```
var items = $('.dropdown_4columns li');
$.each(items,function(i,v) {
    if (i == 14) $(this).wrapAll('<div class="column"></div>');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/dYGpE/)

**or**

```
$('li:eq(14)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().hasClass('dropdown_4columns');
}).wrapAll('<div class="column"></div>');
```

Comment: True, it does work like a charm.  But the question is *"So how can I just split the li items for just the current list"*.  So... every 15th item within a given list.  (Still, +1 for the clean code)